# InaccessibleObjectException in Java Weka when setting CSVSaver instance to convert arfff file to csv

Tags: java, machine-learning, type-conversion, artificial-intelligence, weka

I am learning weka with Java and am trying to convert a `.csv` file to `.arff` but when trying to set the instance for the `CSVSaver` I get an `InaccessibleObjectException`.

```
        ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
        loader.setSource(new File("Friedman-datasets/friedman_datasets/fri_c0_100_5.arff"));
        Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

        CSVSaver saver = new CSVSaver();
        saver.setInstances(data); //error happens here

        saver.setFile(new File("/Users/jacec/OneDrive/Desktop/DMA/Learning weka/convertingfiletypes/converted.csv"));
        saver.writeBatch();
```

**Error Text**

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @4d76f3f8
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectClasses(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:792)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectAllClassesInFromStream(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:690)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.injectMTJCoreClasses(WekaPackageClassLoaderManager.java:118)
    at weka.core.WekaPackageManager.<clinit>(WekaPackageManager.java:255)
    at weka.core.ResourceUtils.readProperties(ResourceUtils.java:241)
    at weka.core.ResourceUtils.readProperties(ResourceUtils.java:184)
    at weka.core.Utils.readProperties(Utils.java:183)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.<clinit>(Capabilities.java:104)
    at weka.core.converters.AbstractSaver.getCapabilities(AbstractSaver.java:219)
    at weka.core.converters.CSVSaver.getCapabilities(CSVSaver.java:403)
    at weka.core.converters.AbstractSaver.setInstances(AbstractSaver.java:162)
    at weka.api.csv2arff.main(csv2arff.java:19)
```

If anyone knows why this is happening as I am following a tutorial with their exact code so I don't know what I'm doing differently

Comment: Make sure you use Java 11. You can get OpenJDK for various operating systems from here: https://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: ah thank you that works. Does weka only work with ~java11?

Comment: Weka's package manager (at least up to 3.8.5 and 3.9.5) performs some low-level operations for loading in packages which are no longer allowed in later versions of Java (from what I've seen). Can't be absolutely sure, but from memory, Java 16 seemed to no longer work.